# Организация базы данных в социальной сети

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Доброго времени суток.
Вот задумался, интересно, а как организована в соц. сетях (facebook, VK) БД связей между пользователями?

Казалось бы, все просто: создал базу `friendship`, в нее 3 поля

`|user_id|recipient_id|status|`

Где
 
`user_id`      - id пользователя
`recipient_id` - id профиля, который имеет какое-либо отношение к пользователю `user_id`

И `status`, куда можно занести "отношение" этих 2-х пользователей (0-подал заявку в друзья, ждем подтверждения, 1-дружим, 2-в черном списке).

Казалось бы, и все, но это мне кажется совершенно нерациональным, так как рост данных в БД примерно можно будет рассчитывать по формуле

`r = x^2`, где `r` - кол-во строк, а `х` - кол-во пользователей.
Совершенно нерациональный подход.

А как бы сделали Вы?

Дело в том, что появилась необходимость сделать нечто похожее по принципу функционирования, но, боюсь, что Мускул повесится от нагрузки.

Заранее спасибо за помощь и ваши варианты :)

Comment: У Вас отношение между Id стремится к каждый с каждым ? Иначе откуда квадрат ? Мне кажется в соц сетях наоборот у большинства Id (из миллионов) десятки (а не миллионы) связей.

Собственно это вопрос о представлении матрицы. Разряженная или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос о том как "хранить" набор друзей - это, пожалуй, один из самых простых вопросов, на который требуется ответить при разработке подобной архитектуры. 200-300 записей в базе *(по одной на каждого добавленного друга)* на пользователя - это смешно, если сравнить их, например, с количеством личных сообщений или даже "лайками" у новостей.

В проектах такого масштаба оптимизация проводится большей частью с помощью грамотно выбранной архитектуры `backend'а` и средств, которые используются для распределенной обработки данных.

Вопрос *"как наиболее эффективным образом сочетать Hadoop, PHP, memcached, Thrift и MySQL"* **намного серьезнее вопроса** *"как бы получше записать друзей в базу данных, чтобы было побыстрее"*.

Тем более, представьте себе, какие средства и время вкладываются в оптмизации алгоритмов поиска, или, например, нахождение и кэширование списка возможных друзей. *Или, например, в написание самодельной высокопроизводительной базы данных с нуля на `C`, как поступили разработчики `Vkontakte`.*

---

Готов предположить, что ваша задача спокойно решается с помощью стандартных средств и производительности `MySQL`. **Не думайте о производительности раньше времени, оптимизируйте только `hotspot'ы`, и то если производительность по каким-либо причинам не устраивает.**

---

Если интересно, про архитектуру `Facebook` можно почитать [**здесь**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479720/what-database-does-facebook-use) и [**здесь.**](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-work-nuts-bolts-technology-explained/)

Answer (score 1):

Кол-во данных описывается формулой **S = K * X**, где X - кол-во пользователей, а К - среднее кол-во друзей. 
С огромным запасом пусть K будет 500 ( в реальности - думаю меньше 50, т.к. есть много фейков, и просто страниц с малым кол-вом друзей ). И тогда у контакта(140М юзеров) таких записей 70млрд.
Но никто не говорит что они хранятся в одной таблице.Например можно иметь 1000 таблиц для каждого из user_id%1000, что даёт средний размер таблицы **K * X / 1000 * (пусть 10байт)** - 750 Мб, что при масштабировании кол-ва таблиц до 10000, даёт всего 75 Мб, что уже совсем не много

Comment: Начнем с того, что на обслуживание нескольких таблиц тратится гораздо больше памяти, чем на одну :))

Для того, чтобы Мускул не развалился нафик при огромных нагрузках - нужно юзать кластер sql серверов + адексатное кэширование (у меня, например, Sphinx + Memcache).... и будет Вам счастье  :)

Comment: Таблицы на разных серверах... И взаимодействия между такими таблицами - минимизированы...

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось проще.

```
$mQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `friendship` WHERE `uid`='".$myid."' || `rid`='".$myid."'");
```

Далее, во время перебора `mysql_fetch_array`-а я тупо проверяю:
Если включ массив `uid` не совпадает с моим `$myid`, то этот `uid` записывается в массив как `id` друга, если совпадает, значит значение этого массива записывается в массив как `id` друга.

Ничего сложного оказывается :)
Нужно просто всего-то немного подумать :)

Comment: Вы вообще понимаете разницу между тем что вы спросили, и тем что сейчас написали?))